# How to localize kendo grid ASP.NET

Tags: localization, grid, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to localize my kendo grid messages like "items per page", "columns". I change language in user's profile. How can I pass user's value to kendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I was working on myself recently I used the following method on the layout page:

```
<!-- Load kendo language and culture scripts -->
@{
    var languageDev = UserManager.GetUserAsync(ContextAccessor.HttpContext.User).Result.UserLanguageCode;
    switch (languageDev)
    {
        case "es":
        {
            <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/cultures/kendo.culture.es.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/messages/kendo.messages.es-ES.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            break;
        }
        case "zh":
        {
            <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/cultures/kendo.culture.zh.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/messages/kendo.messages.zh-CN.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            break;
        }
        case "ru":
        {
            <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/cultures/kendo.culture.ru.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/messages/kendo.messages.ru-RU.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/cultures/kendo.culture.en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/messages/kendo.messages.en-GB.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            break;
        }
    }
    <script type="text/javascript">kendo.culture("@languageDev");</script>
}
```